# CastleWindsor3 + log4net getting started

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, log4net

I followed the steps here (literally): http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx

I have problem whit this row:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net());
```

f.UseLog4Net can't be resolved, the method is not declared in LoggingFacility. Is the tutorial outdated?

So tried this instead:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net));
```

Log4net is not a part of the LoggerImplementation enum.

Found the solution:

I was referencing Castle.Facilities.Logging build for the .net4.0 client framework. By changing my project to full .net 4.0 and update my reference to Castle.Facilities.Logging the method "UseLog4Net()" exist and the enum has a Log4Net element.

Comment: I found the problem. I was referencing Castle.Facilities.Logging build for the .net4.0 client framework. By changing my project to full .net 4.0 and update my reference to Castle.Facilities.Logging the method "UseLog4Net()" exist and the enum has a Log4Net element.

Comment: Add this comment as an answer so this can be closed and even voted for :)